# How do I create an 's' shape in sketch?

Tags: vector, icon, sketch-app

I'm trying to design a circular icon in which you can see a beach, with water washing onto it. So I want to create a squiggly/s shaped layer to resemble water.

I'm new to designing icons in Sketch and can't seem to figure out how to make this shape look good. One way or another, it turns out awkward.

I've tried to construct the water using ovals, but this keeps giving me either hard v shaped corners or awkward lines in general. I feel like I need to 'invert' the circle some how, but I just can't come up with how to do this.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this in Illustrator, but I imagine the same thing will work in Sketch.

Create a rectangle on top of your "sand" layer and under your clipping mask.  then, manipulate your anchor points' handles as I've demonstrated:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it does not work exactly the same but it did help me come to the answer! I create a handle in the middle of the bottom line and used the 'asymmetric' setting to create the shape.